# R Package 'MSwM' has inconsistent result

Tags: r, statistics, time-series, markov

> mod.mswm <- msmFit(lm(y~x),k=2,p=1,sw=rep(T,4),control=list(maxiter=700,parallel=F))
> summary(mod.mswm)
>
> #### I have a inconsistent result in this r packages..
>
> First Running -> regime 1 = "estimate = 0.05"
>
> ```
>              regime 2 = "estimate = 0.90"
> ```
>
> Second Running -> regime 1 = "estimate = 0.90"
>
> ```
>               regime 2 = "estimate = 0.05"
> ```
>
> Please help me..

Comment: Isn't this what one might expect from a package whose middle name is `Switching`?

Comment: yeah.. inconsistent switching

Comment: This is statistics. You were expecting determinacy?

Answer (score 0):

First, I suggest taking a look at the R codes for that function `msmFit` and pay special attention to whether any random number generators are used and whether there is `set.seed` before it. The inconsistent results, from my experience of other packages, are probably due to this reason.

Second, I see there seems to be a "switch" between the two results for the two regimes in terms of the estimates -- that is (to me) a very interesting observation and I am not sure if there is any underlying hidden relationships.

Comment: I still get problem.. Sometimes consistent, sometimes inconsistent.. this is my finally syntax: mod.mswm <- msmFit(lm(y~x),k=2,p=1,sw=rep(T,4),control=list(tol=0.0001,maxiterOuter=0,maxiterInner=0,maxiter=10000,parallel=F))